# Connecting to database using hostname, SID and port number

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle

I have a HOSTNAME=hostname, SID=sid and PORT=port specified for my ORACLE database connection.

I have successfully connected to this database using SQL Developer. What I would like to do now is to connect to the same database in my C# application. How can I achieve that? How should I specify my connection string for SQLConnection instance?

So far, I got this code (the variables: hostname, sid, port, username and password are all Strings and exactly the same as corresponding fields in SQL Developer):

```
String dataSourceFormat = String.Format(@"{0}\{1},{2}", hostname, sid, port);
DbConnectionStringBuilder conStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = dataSourceFormat,
    UserID = username,
    Password = password,
};
DBConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
```

When opening the connection, I always get the same error "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)". Why does the connection work in SQL Developer, but does not in my application?

[EDIT]
I also tried using OracleConnection instance:

```
String dataSourceFormat = String.Format(@"(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = {0})(PORT = {1})))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID  = {2})))", hostname, port, sid);
DbConnectionStringBuilder conStr = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = dataSourceFormat,
    UserID = username,
    Password = password,
};
DBConnection con = new OracleConnection(conStr.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
```

but it results in another error: "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater".

Comment: Is this a SQL Server database? Oracle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618512/how-to-set-proper-path-to-tnsnames-file-in-c-sharp-application/10618629#10618629